# Class implicit cast to integral type (preferably bool) at compiile-time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Suposse we have an integral value wrapper. For example, a boolean wrapper like `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`:

```
template<typename T , T VALUE>
struct integral_value_wrapper
{
    static const T value = VALUE;
};

template<bool VALUE>
using boolean_wrapper = integral_value_wrapper<bool,VALUE>;

using true_wrapper  = boolean_wrapper<true>;
using false_wrapper = boolean_wrapper<false>;
```

We use that boolean wrappers for our own classes. For example, an int checker:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_int : public false_wrapper {};

template<>
struct is_int<int> : public true_wrapper {};


using type = int;

int main()
{
    if( is_int<type>::value ) cout << "type is int" << endl;
}
```

My question is: **Is there any way to make a type (The class that inherits from a bool wrapper in this case) to implicit cast to an integral value?**

This allows me to avoid the use of the `::value` member in boolean expressions, like in the example below:

```
using type = int;

int main()
{
    if( is_int<type> ) cout << "type is int" << endl;  //How I can do that?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide a type where an *expression* is expected. But if you add a conversion operator to your wrapper, like so:

```
template<typename T , T VALUE>
struct integral_value_wrapper
{
    static constexpr T value = VALUE;
    constexpr operator T () const { return value; }
};
```

You can then write:

```
if ( is_int<type>() )
//               ^^
```

Which is what standard type traits do.

Comment: I know the conversion operator, to use the integral wrapper like a functor. But I wanted an implicit cast, to use that wrappers like integral values. What do  you think about this proposal?: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3545.pdf Could help me with this problem?

Comment: @Manu343726: `I know the conversion operator, to use the integral wrapper like a functor`. No, you are confused. First of all, the point is that those wrappers are *types*. You cannot use a type like a value. It is just non-sense (sorry if this sounds harsh). The proposal is about introducing a new call operator, and *that* would allow using that as a functor. But it would still mean that you first have to create instances of that type, so: `is_int<type>()()`. Either use `::value` or instantiate the wrapper as shown in the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. Really use a wrapper of a value to use it like a value sounds a bit... cyclic?. I was looking for a clearer syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Manu343726: No problem, glad I could help - at least partly

Comment: I was reading this again. Hopefully now we have C++14 template aliases!

Comment: @Manu343726: Alias templates were already part of C++11, and are currenty supported by all major compiler vendors.

Comment: oh, sorry about the mistake, I meant C++14 template **variables**

Comment: @Manu343726: Oh, that :) Well, Clang supports them ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8d547af3867137d)), GCC and VS2013 do not yet. Not sure whether I would suggest using them that way though.